# Can someone explain to me why this var is undefined?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying this simple code.

```
var d = new Date();
x = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday", "Wednsday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]; 
d.getDay();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Today is " + x[d];
```

But it doesn't work. It says Today is undefined

Instead it works like this `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="Today is " x[d.getDay()];`

But why?

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. **We can’t run your screenshot as code.**

Answer (score 5):

The method [Date#getDay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) that you use in `d.getDay()` returns the number of the day, but doesn't change `d`, which is still the date object. To use the value returned by the `getDay()` method, you need to assign the result to a variable, or use it directly, like you do in `x[d.getDay()];`.

Because you are using the object `d` using the bracket notation `[]` to access an array index that doesn't exist, you get `undefined` as result.

Since, you don't actually need the date, just assign the day directly to `d`:

```
var d = new Date().getDay()
```

Example:

```js
var d = new Date().getDay();

var x = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Today is " + x[d];
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: @VladNorton - Welcome.  Don't forget to accept the answer :)